# Disable automatic clock on Windows

Tags: c#, windows

We have a c# program running on Windows. The machines is not always connected to a server or internet.
We use timestamps to follow actions on the system.
When the clock is updated during the work session it messes up our system..
Is there any way by code to enable/disable the automatically clock update ?

Comment: Disable the `Windows Time` service, however this really belongs on say SuperUser.

Comment: What if the user spots the date/time hasn't updated (or is just wrong) & updates it manually.